# Haskell IO: remove a random element from a tree

Tags: list, haskell, build, io, tree

Consider the following type to represent trees:

```
data Tree a = Empty
            | Leaf a
            | Fork (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

I need help definig the function `removeRandom' :: Tree a -> IO (Tree a)` that receives a tree with at least a leaf and returns the result of removing a random leaf from the tree (replacing it with Empty). The exercise had a suggestion: use the function `randomRIO :: Random a => (a,a) -> IO a` to generate the order of the element to remove

EDIT: trying method 2 of user Thomas

```
removeRandom' :: Tree a -> IO (Tree a)
removeRandom' t = let lengthTree = numbelems t
                  in do x <- randomRIO (0,lengthTree -1)
                        return (remove x t)

numbelems :: Tree a -> Int
numbelems Empty = 0
numbelems Leaf x = 1
numbelems Fork l r = (numbelems l) + (numbelems r)

remove :: Int -> Tree a -> Tree a
remove _ (Leaf x) = Empty
remove n (Fork l r) = let lengthLeft = numbelems l
                      in if (n>lengthLeft) then Fork l (remove (n-lengthLeft r)
                         else Fork (remove n l) r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to approach this problem

1. Convert to a list, remove the element, and convert back to a tree.

   - **Pros**: Simple to implement, you already have toList, all you need is fromList, and you can implement your solution simply as

     ```
     removeAt :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
     removeAt n as = a ++ tail s where (a, s) = splitAt n

     removeRandom' tree = do
         element <- randomRIO (0, length tree)
         return $ fromList $ removeAt element $ toList tree
     ```
   - **Cons**: This method is not "True" to the problem statement `removing a random leaf from the tree (replacing it with Empty)` and will likely give you a brand new tree with no `Empty` values in it. I have only provided this as an option in an attempt to show where your `toList` method ends up.
2. Descend into the tree, until you hit the element to be removed, then rebuild the tree on the way back up

   - **Pros**: The meat of the algorithm is "Pure" as in, does not touch `IO`. You only actually need IO for a moment within `removeRandom'`. You can likely write a solution that looks a bit like this (interesting parts left blank ;).

     ```
     removeAt :: Int -> Tree a -> Tree a
     removeAt n tree = walk 0 tree
       where
         walk i Empty = ...
         walk i (Fork l r) = ...
         walk i l@(Leaf _)
           | i == n    = ...
           | otherwise = ...

     removeRandom' tree = do
         element <- randomRIO (0, length tree)
         return $ removeAt element tree
     ```
   - **Cons**:  More complicated to implement, you need to know how to traverse back "up" a tree, rebuilding in your wake, and you will need to know how to write a recursive function with an accumulator such that you can track your position in the tree.

Either way you decide to go, you will need to write a function `length :: Tree a -> Int` that counts the number of leaves to use as input to `randomRIO` (which is an action that simply produces a random value in a given range).

Comment: Ok. I added my try of method two to my question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Could you also help me on building the fromList function? I know it's not relevant to method two but I think it might be useful in another context

Comment: Your implementation of numbelems is spot-on, but your implementation of remove is not. The condition for replacing a Leaf with Empty is when your accumulator reaches zero. Consequently, you have to count all the leaves you have encountered so far, and remove them from your accumulator.

Comment: Ok I will try your approach. However, I think mine also works. Can you give me an example of a tree where it fails?

Comment: After looking again at your solution, I think you are right, it does work. Well done.

Comment: Thanks. I am having a lot of difficulty seeing what I should put in your accumulator version. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: I'm giving you credit for the answer as it lead to the answer exposed in my question. Thanks a lot for explaining the various methods of approach and their shortcomings. They were essential to elaborate my answer. Thanks!